# Keeping the spelling 'Kristtorn' while sounding like 'Kriston' - possible with diacritics?

Tags: pronunciation, names, language-formation

I want to change my name to *Kristtorn*, which, when pronounced in English, sounds like 'orn' as in *horn* (/ɔːn/), but I want to make it sound like  'kriston' (/krɪstɒn/).

However what I am wondering is if using a [diaeresis/umlaut (also known as a *tréma*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic))<sup>[difference between umlaut and diaeresis](https://www.babbel.com/en/magazine/the-history-of-the-umlaut-and-the-diaeresis-and-how-to-pronounce-them/)</sup> (which are the two dots placed above a letter) would make this work.

For example:  The letter `i` becomes `ï` through the use of the diacritic.

This would be used with the 'o' in *Kristtorn*, to make *Kristtörn.*
 So as the ö when pronounced in English sounds like "er" as in *her* (/əː/), what sound would this produce (when pronounced in English)?

Would it be 'kristen' (/krɪstən/) or possibly 'kriston' (/krɪstɒn/), given that the *er* sound and the 'r' after the 'ö' sound would come out that way when spoken aloud?

Also, does using the *Ø* vowel (or any 
other symbol) in any part of the word Kristtorn cause it to sound differently? Would the use of this vowel make the desired sound?

I'd love to hear what people come up with here, but mainly what I'm going for is some phonetic way of pronouncing the word as *Kriston* while keeping the original spelling of 'Kristtorn' intact.

Comment: If you spell your name Kristtörn, people who know German will pronounce it kristø̞ən (with a vowel that doesn't exist in English, but sounds more or less like kriston), and everybody else will ignore the umlaut and pronounce it kristorn.

Comment: Thankyou Peter, that was very helpful. So what your saying is, only to those who speak German would pronounce it that way, but what about people from Scandinavia for example who also employ the use of this vowel? Also to everyone else who doesn't know this, would it be worth at least correcting them as they would be pronouncing the word incorrectly due to not knowing about the particular usage of this vowel?

Comment: As @PeterShor says, most English speakers, unless they have studied foreign languages, ignore diacritics. I'm sure I've heard the company name Kärcher pronounced Kar-cher in TV commercials. The Scandinavian  Ø is  even less known. I think all you can do is explain how to pronounce your name every time you introduce yourself to someone who has seen it written down!

Comment: I think the only thing you can do with spelling Kristtorn is accept the pronunciation with R; unless you want to repeatedly tell people "the R is silent" whenever they mispronounce it.

Comment: Ive just thought of something, if I were to spell the name 'kristø̞ən' instead. Would this still translate as Kristtorn in Norwegian while keeping the near enough pronounciation of Kriston?

Comment: This site isn't the place to ask about how Norwegians would pronounce a word.

Comment: Its more to check whether the spelling would come out the same rather than to query its pronounciation at this stage, especially since that first part was answered. But I am curious as to whether it would translate in its spelling the same way?

Comment: @Lordology, if I could clarify your point. Am I right in thinking that it doesnt matter if it is spelt as 'Kristø̞ən' or as 'Kristtörn', is the pronounciation of the sound Kriston contingent upon the exact diacritic used or is it more subjective as one petitrien suggested in the answer?

Comment: @Peter Shor Are you native to Norway or Scandanavia? Additionally If I were to spell the name kristø̞ən, would that then produce the sound Kriston? But would still keep the meaning of the word Holly rather than spelling it as Kristtörn? As Kristtorn means Holly in Norwegian.

Comment: @PeterShor Yep: I should've kept my mouth shut. And if you are native to Native to Scandinavia/Norway as OP suggests, you might have a good shot at answering the question, for once and all?

Comment: I'm not native to Norway. I've just visited Scandinavian countries, and know a tiny bit about how to pronounce words when I seen them spelled.

Answer (score 3):

Words and letters do not produce any sound, people do using their speech organs and the pulmonic airstream.

There doesn't seem to be any straightforward way to elicit the desired pronunciation /ˈkrɪstɒn/ through spelling, *ton* at the end of a person's name or in placenames is typically realized in a reduced form such as /tn̩/.  Anything with an *r* will be mispronounced in rhotic varieties of English.

Perhaps *Krist-On* could work but I'm afraid yours will be the lot of Rupert Psmith, Wodehouse's character, that had to tell people how to pronounce his name and specify that the *p* was silent as in *pshrimp*.